# Loading picture from database to jquery slider using php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I am trying to load pictures from database to jquery slider
infact what is stored at database is the name of the picture

i implemented this code, it's working without errors but it showing me nothing at slider all is empty

```
<div id="slider">
<?php
    while ($result = mysqli_fetch_object($banner)):
?>
    <img src="images/banner/<? $banner['picture'];?>/" width="950" height="400"alt=""      title="<strong><? echo $banner['title'];?></strong><span><? echo $banner['description'];?>    </span>" />
<?php
endwhile
?>
</div>
```

name of the table at database is banner in which i have id(INT), picture(varchar 50) title(varchar(100), description(longblob)

query is working and returning number of selected rows
but nothing is shown

Comment: Why is there a trailing slash at the img src?

Comment: try changing `src` to `src=/images/banner/` -- omitting the leading slash makes links relative to current dir, not the domain name and might be leading to problems. Other than that, more code is needed.

Comment: Open developer tools or firebug (depending on your browser, could be opened with f12) and see what is exact value of src for you images. That will help you to find a problem

Comment: You are missing an `echo` before `$banner['picture']`

Answer (score 2):

You need to `echo` the result rather than just use the variable...

```
<div id="slider">
<?php
    while ($result = mysqli_fetch_object($banner)):
?>
    <img src="images/banner/<?php echo $banner['picture'];?>" width="950" height="400" alt="" title="<strong><? echo $banner['title'];?></strong><span><?php echo $banner['description'];?></span>" />
<?php
endwhile;
?>
</div>
```